# Fill a textbox with the current date in dd/mm/yy format on formload

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I am trying to set default date to a textbox inside my asp.net web form, using jquery on form load.For that I am using the function :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" autocomplete="off" id="datepicker2" name="datepicker2" />
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.toLocaleDateString();
    document.getElementById("datepicker2").defaultValue = n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But when I added this to my solution date format changes to mm/dd/yyyy , where I am expecting it in dd/mm/yyyy format.

why this `toLocaleDateString();` is not working on my solution ?
`datepicker2` is a `datepicker` . I have a function `datepicker()` for calendar view which also gives output in dd/mm/yyyy format when i select a date using mouse.

So,how can I fill datepicker2 with Current date in dd/mm/yyyy format ???? 
Note: This issue happens **only when I am using FireFox** !!

Comment: 25/07/2017  is dd/mm/yy format. so what'e your problem (i checked it chrome/firefox/safari)

Comment: @AlivetoDie in my solution its 07/25/2017 (on firefox )

Comment: i think you have some other code which manipulates data

Comment: @AlivetoDie your local date settings and OP's are probably different which is why `toLocaleDateString()` is used in the first place

Comment: snippet works perfect on every browser i know that..!! but in my solution `datepicker2` is a datepicker and on the above design its just a textbox .!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toLocaleDateString()` displays the date in the user's locale, so it depends of the client (as I am in Spain, it displays in dd/mm/yyyy as that is my default locale, but it will be different for someone in USA, for example). For what you want to do, try:

```
function myFunction() {
   var d = new Date();
   var day = ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2);
   var month= ('0' + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
   var year = d.getFullYear(); 
   var n = day + '/' + month + '/' + year ;
   document.getElementById("datepicker2").defaultValue = n;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" autocomplete="off" id="datepicker2" name="datepicker2" />
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.toLocaleDateString("en-IN");
    document.getElementById("datepicker2").defaultValue = n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Change the toLocateDateString as below

```
var n = d.toLocaleDateString("en-IN");
```